# Can't log in to my Chromebook after clearing all cookies and autofill data by accident, any way to fix?

Tags: chromebook, google-chrome-os

When I was using my Chromebook, I accidentally cleared all of my cookies and autofill data. After I restarted the Chromebook, I couldn't login to my account. Whenever I try, the screen goes black for longer than usual then goes back to the login screen. Any way to fix this? On Developer Mode with OS Verification turned off.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you need to proceed now is login to the Chromebook by entering the true Username and Password of your account. If you forgot the new password which you have set, then you can try by entering the old password.